# crud operations formdata trought spring restTemplate connector / gate / proxy

Tags: spring-mvc, angular

I am creating connection between Angular2 app and data source with spring rest separation.

It looks like

**{{ Angular2App <=> SpringApp <=> DataSourceApp }}**

Can I use any api for this functionality?

Angular app is isolated from datasource app.

Angular post for file upload with FormData:

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('filedata', filedata);
this.http.post('/rest/upload' + this.nodeId), form).map(response => response.json());
```

**How to receive FormData posted in angular app and pass it further by restTemplate request to dataSource?**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/upload", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@PathVariable("nodeId") final String nodeId) {
    return this.restTemplate.exchange(dataUploadUrl + nodeId, HttpMethod.POST, String.class);
}
```

Comment: You are expecting path varialble @PathVariable("nodeId") but it is not present in the post request.

Comment: I fixed it, it was wrong but irrelevant for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `@RequestBody`, How about:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@Valid @RequestBody final String nodeId){
 //your code here 
}
```